Some issues with new design
First, very minor:
Here is the review queue view:

The green bar is a different and IMO conflicting green than the buttons. You see more of it if you hover over the meter.
The same is visible in the profile/activity page. You see different greens in reputation values than reputation bars and graphs.

Second, there seems to still be the old beta icon in /favicon.ico. One of my devices has a browser that seems to prefer it to the HTML-defined one. (This has since been fixed or fixed itself.)

Third issue. The "choose which badge to track" button in the activity screen does not work. The window that opens is in the background and cannot be interacted with.  (This has since been fixed.)

I agree that the colors are a bit off, but I would consider that a very minor issue. Could be on the todo list. As for the favicon.ico, it could be that the icon is cached in the browser, possibly in the favorites section. If you have a problem like this, first try and clear the cache and hit refresh. If that doesn't work please list the browser version etc. here. My Windows browsers seem to handle the icon just fine.

@MaartenBodewes, definitely minor! However, the icon thing is not a cache on my end. I tried directly downloading it with wget and got the beta icon. Could be caching at some CDN node, of course.

Ah, yes, that would indeed point to a service error instead of a design error. Still interesting to note though, maybe something for the IT ops team at SE.

Probably better to create a post per issue, i.e. make meta work like a bug reporting tool. I don't think that last issue (confirmed!) is minor at all.

@MaartenBodewes, I'm lazy so I'll edit the title instead :P


Fixing this isn't as simple as it seems. So we will keep an eye on that issue and see what's possible. 2) It's cache issue for sure. 3) Yeap, we are working on this.


I think it's not minor, the two different greens are a pain in the eye, e.g., on the user page. I think the greens should be harmonized (favouring the more blueish "design green").

